# Python: Execução do código lenta e outros problemas

Tags: python

Caros colegas,

Alguém pode me esclarecer o que pode estar ocorrendo?

Em resumo, trata-se de um código para ler células de uma planilha, ordenar e transportar para uma nova planilha.

**O problema:** O código não executa e não apresenta nenhum erro. Estou usando o PyCharm. Passei o dia de ontem e de hoje testando e, o interessante é que o DEBUG não apresenta erro e executa o código tranquilamente.

**Para entenderem o que eu estou criando:** Eu peguei os resultados da LOTOFACIL (jogo loteria) e coloquei numa planilha excel. A planilha foi nomeada de **lotofacil.xlsx**. A planilha tem 1664 linhas e 15 colunas.

Veja um exemplo da planilha...[image: Planilha Excel 2007]

Pois bem, o meu código está assim...

```
    import openpyxl




wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('lotofacil.xlsx') #abre o arquivo
nome_plan = wb.sheetnames[0] #identifica o nome da planilha de indice zero
planilha = wb[nome_plan] #entra na planilha indicada


linhas = planilha.max_row #qtd de linhas
colunas = planilha.max_column #qtd de colunas

lista = [] #valores de cada linha são adicionados e depois excluídos


novo_arquivo = openpyxl.Workbook() #abre novo arquivo excel
nome_planNova = novo_arquivo.sheetnames[0] #identifica o nome da planilha de indice zero
planilhaNova = novo_arquivo[nome_planNova] #entra na planilha indicada
novo_arquivo.save('loto_python.xlsx') #salva a planilha nova


#cria um loop.
x=1
while linhas >= x: #enquanto o número de linhas da planilha (1664), for maior ou igual a 'x' o programa executa.
    y1=1
    while y1 <= colunas: #enquanto o número de colunas da planilha(15), for maior ou igual a 'y' o programa executa.
        celula = planilha.cell(row=x, column=y1).value #recebe o conteudo da celula.
        lista.append(celula) #adiciona o conteúdo da célula na lista. A lista terá o tamanho de 15 posições.
        y1+=1

    lista.sort() #ordena a lista, do menor para o maior.

    y2=1
    while y2 <= colunas:
        planilhaNova.cell(row=x, column=y2).value = lista[y2-1] #pega cada item da lista
        novo_arquivo.save('loto_python.xlsx') #salva novamente a planilha nova
        y2+=1

    lista = [] #esvazia a lista. Isso permite manter o loop e seguir para a linha seguinte.

    x+=1
```

Veja a saída, já na nova planilha... pelo DEBUG.
Lembrando: a execução normal não funciona.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A "execução normal não funciona", você diz que não executa e não dá erro. Se não executa necessariamente dará erro; ou executa, só não gera o resultado esperado. Pode esclarecer melhor? Você precisa ordenar cada linha de forma crescente?

Comment: Claro Anderson, esclareço. Eu disse: "O código não executa e não apresenta nenhum erro." A execução normal não gera nenhum tipo de alerta de erro e também não gera o resultado esperado. Qual é o resultado esperado? Resposta: A saída apresentada na imagem anexada. O interessante é que o DEBUG executa o programa sem apresentar erro e gera o resultado esperado, porém, isso não me ajuda. Gostaria que o programa fosse automático e não necessitasse de eu ter que executar pelo DEBUG e ficar apertando a tecla "F8" mais de 53.248 vezes.

Comment: Consegue disponibilizar um exemplo de arquivo xlsx de entrada que reproduza o erro?

Comment: Oi Anderson. O arquivo excel de entrada não é o problema, uma vez que desse só é lido os valores. Até aí tudo bem. A questão é que quando executo o código, o PyCharm não apresenta nenhuma mensagem de erro, mas cria o arquivo excel de saída. O excel de saída não abre, pois dá erro.

Comment: A ideia de disponibilizar o arquivo é justamente podermos executar o código e tentar reproduzir o erro. Acredito que você consiga fazer inclusive um [mcve] no https://repl.it

Comment: Ah sim. Claro. Vou fazer isso agora...

Comment: Pronto. Segue o link do Google Drive. --> https://drive.google.com/open?id=1YKf-8OtIej_Oqpz2lrHBt5oQgOlHbplD

Comment: Oi Anderson. Nossa! Assim que terminei de falar com você, coloquei o código para rodar e fiquei aguardando, aguardando, aguardando e, mais de  1 (uma) hora depois o código finalizou a execução, sem erros. O programa funcionou! Porém achei extremamente demorado. Há alguma solução para isso?!

Comment: Sim, tenta colocar o `novo_arquivo.save` somente no final do arquivo, fora dos laços de repetição.

Comment: Fiz o que você disse... Executou em segundos. Obrigado mesmo! Aliás, vamos ficar rico, Anderson! hahahahaha Um grande abraço!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apenas para iterar a solução dada, da maneira que você fez, chamando o método `save()` dentro do laço de repetição, você estará salvando o arquivo em disco múltiplas vezes (15 x 1664 = 24.960 vezes precisamente). Leitura e escrita em disco é uma das tarefas mais lentas que há em um computador, imagina fazer isso quase 25 mil vezes com um arquivo de 15 colunas e 1664 linhas. Obviamente que você não precisa fazer isso. O seu objeto `novo_arquivo` já representa seu arquivo inteiro, então basta você modificá-lo, persistindo todas as mudanças apenas em memória e apenas no final da execução persistí-las em disco uma única vez.

Para tal, basta colocar a linha de código:

```
novo_arquivo.save('loto_python.xlsx')
```

No final do programa, fora de todos os laços de repetição.